# Get file name when printing

Tags: windows, printing

Is there a way to detect the file name of a file when a user prints from any application, somwhere in the printer events? I am looking for a windows api where I can determine what file is being printed.

Answer (score 2):

Print jibs are opened with names but typically this doesn't mean the filename - the names which are displayed in the print queue are accessible by querying the printer driver directly I believe.

Answer (score 1):

The printer driver does not have any external API for finding the filename. I assume you would be looking at creating some kind of systray agent sort of app that would be monitoring print queues for jobs being sent. If so -

1. Refer to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/196805 for a microsoft tool that allows you to monitor print queues for print job status
2. Refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff562742%28v=vs.85%29.aspx which explains how Windows supports printer change notifications. You can create an app that registers for this and get handle to the Print Queue. Once you get a handle you can call the GetPrinter and GetJob APIs to get access to the JOB_INFO_2 structure. The pDocumentName in the JOB_INFO_2 structure is the name of the file

Hope this helps. If so, please vote a +1 :)

Comment: Your link #1 is dead, I google for some Microsoft print queue monitor but I just found this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc784766%28v=ws.10%29.aspx
Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not, at least not reliably. Keep in mind that there may not be a file name at all. For example, I could open an application like notepad, type some stuff, and print. What file am I printing? None.

In the above scenario most applications will provide some sort of default file name like "untitled", and sometimes you can find that name by parsing the print job's name. For example, if you call `GetJob`, the `JOB_INFO_1` struct's `pDocument` member will contain a pointer to the print job's name, and that name will often contain the file name.

However, every application formats it differently, and some don't provide it at all. So the answer is you can find the file name perhaps 75% of the time with a lot of effort, but there simply is no 100% solution.